# create a view that autoresizes based on a UIView's subview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiview

I have a UIView called containerView in which I have a few UILabel's and UITextView in it and I am adjusting the final height of the containerView by later on iterating the height of it's subviews and summing them up. Is it possible to have this height automatically adjusted? I am adjusting the height of the subviews using something like this:

```
CGFloat desiredHeight = [object.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:15] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.imageView_.frameWidth , CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeClip].height;
```

Also is it even possible to adjust the y origin of a particular subview to be always below another subview? For example in this containerView I have two UILabel, A and B. I wanted B to be always below A. As of now what I am doing is calculating the following in layoutSubviews:

```
[B setFrameY:A.frameY + A.frameHeight];
```

Is it possible to achieve something like this with auto resizing mask? The reason I can't use a constant is because A's frameHeight is dynamic depending the length of the text.

Answer (score 0):

I think the short answer to your question is that no, there is no autoresizing of a view on the basis of its subviews. In terms of your latter question (adjusting a control's frame on the basis of another control), you should check out the various "auto layout" videos from [WWDC 2012](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/).

When I originally answered this, I think that I may have just provided solutions that, upon rereading your question, I think you may have already implemented. My apologies. Anyway, I include my old answer for your reference.

**Old answer:**

On your first question, no, I think you have to iterate through your subviews to accomplish what you want. I don't think you can do anything with autosizing masks (those are designed to go the other way, adjust the frames of subviews based upon the change of the bounds of their superview). And while iOS 6 promises some enhancements, I don't think it tackles your specific challenge.

You could obviously do something programmatically pretty easily, though. You could do something like the following:

```
- (void)resizeView:(UIView *)view
{
    CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0);
    CGPoint lowerRight;

    // maybe you don't want to do anything if there are no subviews

    if ([view.subviews count] == 0)
        return;

    // find the most lowerright corner that will encompass all of the subviews

    for (UIView *subview in view.subviews)
    {
        // you might want to turn off autosizing on the subviews because they'll change their frames when you resize this at the end,
        // which is probably incompatible with the superview resizing that we're trying to do.

        subview.autoresizingMask = 0;

        // if you have containers within containers, you might want to do this recursively.
        // if not, just comment out the following line

        [self resizeView:subview];

        // now let's see where the lower right corner of this subview is

        lowerRight.x = subview.frame.origin.x + subview.frame.size.width;
        lowerRight.y = subview.frame.origin.y + subview.frame.size.height;

        // and adjust the maxsize accordingly, if we need to

        if (lowerRight.x > maxSize.width)
            maxSize.width = lowerRight.x;
        if (lowerRight.y > maxSize.height)
            maxSize.height = lowerRight.y;
    }

    // maybe you want to add a little margin?!?

    maxSize.width += 10.0;
    maxSize.height += 10.0;

    // adjust the bounds of this view accordingly

    CGRect bounds = view.bounds;
    bounds.size = maxSize;
    view.bounds = bounds;
}
```

Just call that on any "container" view you might (probably best to not confuse this with proper view controller containment, which is a different beast) want to resize based upon it's subviews. Note, I just adjust the size (assuming you don't want to move the subviews or the view's `origin`, too, which you could do easily if you want). I also made this go recursively, but maybe you don't want to. Your call.

On your second question, moving label B to be underneath label A is pretty easy:

```
CGRect frame = b.frame;
frame.origin.y = a.frame.origin.y + a.frame.size.height;
b.frame = frame;
```